# number of rows of .SD

Tags: r, data.table

If I have the following simple datatable:

```
DT <- data.table(VAL = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 10, replace = TRUE),Group = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)))
```

I can calc the mean via:

```
DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x){mean(x)}),by=Group]
```

I could also use:

```
DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x){sum(x)/.N}),by=Group]
```

But my question is, why does the following NOT work:

```
DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x){sum(x)/nrow(x)}),by=Group]
```

From my understanding, .SD is a sub datatable of the full datatable, so via function(x) I should be able to refer to the number of rows of x - or in other words, why can I calculate sum(x), but not nrow(x) in .SD? Did not find anything in the documentation in this regard.

Comment: inside `function(x){sum(x)/nrow(x)}`, `x` is a vector and its `dim` is `NULL` so there are no rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.SD` is a `data.table`, but when you `lapply` over it, each `x` value is a *column vector*, for which `nrow` does not work. If you were to do `length` instead, it returns the number of rows.

```
DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x){sum(x)/length(x)}),by=Group]
#    Group VAL
# 1:     A 2.0
# 2:     B 1.6
```

Comment: There's also NROW for folks who really like treating vectors as tables.

Comment: It's not clear from OP's description why you wouldn't use `sum(x)/.N` or even just `mean(x)`.